# transparent colour being shown some of the time

Tags: c++, photoshop, directx-9

I am using a LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 to hold my image.

This is the function used to display my picture.

```
int drawcharacter(SPRITE& person, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9& image)
{
position.x = (float)person.x;
position.y = (float)person.y;
sprite_handler->Draw(
image, 
&srcRect,
NULL,
&position,
D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255));
return 0;
}
```

According to the book I have the RGB colour shown as the last parameter will not be displayed on screen, this is how you create transparency.

This works for the most part but leaves a pink line around my image and the edge of the picture. After trial and error I have found that if I go back into photoshop I can eliminate the pink box by drawing over it with the pink colour. This can be see with the ships on the left.

I am starting to think that photoshop is blending the edges of the image so that background is not all the same shade of pink though I have no proof.[image]

Can anyone help fix this by programming or is the error in the image?

If anyone is good at photoshop can they tell me how to fix the image, I use png mostly but am willing to change if necessary.

edit: texture creation code as requested

```
    character_image = LoadTexture("character.bmp", D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,0,255));
if (character_image == NULL)
    return 0;
```

Comment: 1) What is the `LoadTexture()` function? 2) I assume you really use `character.png` there, not `character.bmp`, right?

Comment: @vines LoadTexture is part of direct x, i did not make it and yes I use bmp and png, been changing to png to try and solve this problem.

Comment: BMP format doesnt't support alpha channel. It won't work. PNG does, it will work, if the alpha channel is actually contained in the file. Check it with some image viewer: you shouldn't see the coloured background rectangle, only the foreground freely "floating". And yes, if LoadTexture is really a part of DirectX, could you please give a link to its documentation?

Comment: Also: try D3DXCreateTextureFromFile() instead...

Answer (score 1):

You are loading a BMP image, which does not support transparency natively - the last parameter `D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,0,255)` is being used to add transparency to an image which doesn't have any. The problem is that the color must match exactly, if it is off even by only one it will not be converted to transparent and you will see the near-magenta showing through.

Save your images as 24-bit PNG with transparency, and if you load them correctly there will be no problems. Also don't add the magenta background before you save them.

Comment: if you had bothered to read my question properly you would see that this is what I am doing and am asking why the image edge and sprite outline is going off buy enough to mess with it. also you will see that I changed the bmp to a png as a test and found no difference.

Comment: what do you mean by load them properly as a png with transparency loaded with the function shown produces the bars at the top of my image.

Comment: @Skeith, the example you show loads a BMP. If you're saving the image as a PNG without any transparency you will get the same result. Since you didn't show the source to LoadTexture it's impossible to know if you're loading the transparency correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As you already use PNG, you can just store the alpha value there directly from Photoshop. PNG supports transparency out of the box, and it can give better appearance than what you get with transparent colour.

It's described in http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/textures.html (for example).

Comment: if you look at the image the bars at the top have what you suggest. Either it is not supported or needs a different direct x function to do.

Comment: @Skeith: see the link in the edited answer, it might help also. Or provide your texture creation code, so that we could analyse it :)

Comment: not sure how texture creation code will help but il put it up

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is anti-aliasing the edge of the image. If it determines that 30% of a pixel is inside the image and 70% is outside, it sets the alpha value for that pixel to 70%. This gives a much smoother result than using a pixel-based transparency mask. You seem to be throwing these alpha values away, is that right? The pink presumably comes from the way that Photoshop displays partially transparent pixels.

Comment: yes... maybe, it sounds like what I'm seeing. How can I make photoshop just have a solid colour and make no changes to it ?

Comment: That's not what you want to do! You want to find a way to use those alpha values in Direct3D. But now I'm out of my depth.

Comment: That's exactly where PNG is going to help!

Comment: @Skeith since you are using BMP you could just open up the image in paint and crop it. Yes, it is one step more but it is a quick fix ;-)

Comment: @RedX look at the sprite closely there is a pink outline on the sprite itself.